# Visualização de Variável no Visual Studio não funciona

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Boa tarde, poderiam me ajudar, já faz um tempo que o meu Visual Studio está deste jeito [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que deveria estar com uma setinha para visualizar o objeto, isto está atrapalhando muito, desde já agradeço

Comment: Filipe, eu tive o mesmo problema quando estava usando componentes de terceiros e ele expirou (OZCODE), se voce utiliza Resharper, ou qualquer um desses foi que causou na minha máquina, tente reinstalar os componentes ou atualizá-los.

Comment: Estou vendo se tem atualizações pendentes

Comment: Deu certo, eu tive que apenas atualizar o VS

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Coloquei a soluçao como resposta pra facilitar p/ quek pesquisar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atualize o VS e todos os componentes, não há necessidade de reinstalar

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, como o @Thiago Loureiro  disse, eu tive apenas que atualizar o Visual Studio, ainda não sei a causa raiz, mas muito obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

tive o mesmo problema e só resolveu reinstalando o VS2017, mas eu usei a "Janela Imediata" por um tempo pra quebrar o galho que faz a mesma coisa...[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]